# issue with pandas and semilog for boxplot

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I have a `pandas` `dataframe` that has columns:

'video' and 'link' of click values

with an index of datetime. For some reason, when I use semilogy and boxplot with the video series, I get the error

```
ValueError: Data has no positive values, and therefore can not be log-scaled.
```

but when I do it on the 'link' series I can draw the boxplot correctly.

I have verified that **both** the 'video' and 'link' series has NaN values and positive values.

Any thoughts on why this is occurring? Below is what I've done to verify that this is the case

**Below is sample code:**

```
#get all the not null values of video to show that there are positive
temp=a.types_pivot[a.types_pivot['video'].notnull()]
print temp

#get a count of all the NaN values to show both 'video' and 'link' has NaN
count = 0 
for item in a.types_pivot['video']:
    if(item.is_integer() == False):
        count += 1

#try to draw the plots
print "there is %s nan values in video" % (count)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,6),dpi=50)
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.semilogy()
plt.boxplot(a.types_pivot['video'].values)
```

**Here is relevant output from the code for video series**

```
    type                       link   video
    created_time

    2011-02-10 15:00:51+00:00   NaN   5
    2011-02-17 17:50:38+00:00   NaN   5
    2011-03-22 14:04:56+00:00   NaN   5
```

there is 5463 nan values in video
    
I run the same exact code except I do

```
a.types_pivot['link']
```

and I am able to draw the boxplot.

**Below is the relevant output from the link series**

```
Index: 5269 entries, 2011-01-24 20:03:58+00:00 to 2012-06-22 16:56:30+00:00
Data columns:
link        5269  non-null values
photo       0  non-null values
question    0  non-null values
status      0  non-null values
swf         0  non-null values
video       0  non-null values
dtypes: float64(6)
```

there is 216 nan values in link

```
Using the describe function

a.types_pivot['video'].describe()

<pre>
count    22.000000
mean     16.227273
std      15.275040
min       1.000000
25%       5.250000
50%       9.500000
75%      23.000000
max      58.000000
</pre>
```

Comment: Did you try removing NaNs from `a.types_pivot['video'].values`?

Comment: Great point Zhenya! Yes, I did try that. `plt.boxplot(temp['video'])` by using my temp variable that I had the non null values and it did work. I do not understand why it doesn't work when I call it directly since it works for the 'link' series. If it works, then I can easily use pandas .boxplot and .hist functions with semilog to compare the data

Answer (score 1):

**Note: I'm unable to upload images due to some issue with imgur. I'll try again later.**

Take advantage of pandas matplotlib helper / wrappers by calling pd.DataFrame.boxplot(). I believe this will take care of the NaN values for you. It will also put both Series in the same plot so you can easily compare data.

**Example**
Create a dataframe with some NaN values and negative values

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5))    
In [8]: df.ix[2:4,3] = np.nan
In [9]: df.ix[2:3,4] = -0.45
In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.391882  0.776331  0.875009  0.350585  0.154517
1  0.772635  0.657556  0.745614  0.725191  0.483967
2  0.057269  0.417439  0.861274       NaN -0.450000
3  0.997749  0.736229  0.084077       NaN -0.450000
4  0.886303  0.596473  0.943397       NaN  0.816650
5  0.018724  0.459743  0.472822  0.598056  0.273341
6  0.894243  0.097513  0.691781  0.802758  0.785258
7  0.222901  0.292646  0.558909  0.220400  0.622068
8  0.458428  0.039280  0.670378  0.457238  0.912308
9  0.516554  0.445004  0.356060  0.861035  0.433503
```

Note that I can count the number of NaN values like so:

```
In [14]: df[3].isnull().sum()   # Count NaNs in the 4th column
Out[14]: 3
```

A box plot is simply:

```
In [16]: df.boxplot()
```

You could create a semi-log boxplot, for example, by:

```
In [23]: np.log(df).boxplot()
```

Or, more generally, modify / transform to you heart's content, and then boxplot.

```
In [24]: df_mod = np.log(df).dropna()    
In [25]: df_mod.boxplot()
```